# How to simulate iPad camera to get image for App Store?

Tags: ios6, camera, app-store

I have an iPad app where I display an image of the customer.  I need to simulate that so I can submit the images to the App Store (Manage your applicatilons).  I have searched (Google and SO), but found nothing.

I would imagine I could take an image using the iPad, but then how do I get it onto my Mac and where do I place it so my app (with a slight temporary modification) can access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the home button and the lock button at the same time to take a screenshot of your iPad screen. Then you can import the photo like normal, or email it to yourself.